# merge separates multidimensional array

Tags: php

When I do `print_r($_FILES);` the result is

```
Array
(
    [one] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => one1.jpg
                    [1] => one2.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php81D9.tmp
                    [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\php81F9.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 129859
                    [1] => 134437
                )

        )

    [two] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => two1.jpg
                    [1] => two2.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php81FA.tmp
                    [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\php820A.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 138108
                    [1] => 142492
                )

        )

)
```

When I do this:

```
    foreach ($_FILES as $color => $value)
        {
            foreach ($value['name'] as $name)
                {
                    $named['name'] = $name;
                    $nameds[] = $named ;
                } 
        }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($nameds);
```

And the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => one1.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => one2.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => two1.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => two2jpg
        )

)
```

^that is the expected result that I want to achieve. But the rest of the key are not inserted there (only the `name`). I want all the keys are there like `type`, `tmp_name` and so on.

So, the final result would be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => one1.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php81D9.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 129859
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => one2.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php81F9.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 134437
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => two1.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php81FA.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 138108
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => two2jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php820A.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 142492
        )

)
```

I wonder if anyone can show me how is the simplest way to do this.

Comment: So you want every element from `$_FILES` to be inserted in a new nested array?

Comment: yes, that's what i want. :) thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php

$_FILES = Array
(
    "one" => Array
        (
            "name" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "one1.jpg",
                    "1" => "one2.jpg"
                ),

            "type" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "image/jpeg",
                    "1" => "image/jpeg"
                ),

            "tmp_name" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php81D9.tmp",
                    "1" => "C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php81F9.tmp"
                ),

            "error" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "0",
                    "1" => "0"
                ),

            "size" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "129859",
                    "1" => "134437"
                )

        ),
    "two" => Array
        (
            "name" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "two1.jpg",
                    "1" => "two2.jpg"
                ),

            "type" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "image/jpeg",
                    "1" => "image/jpeg"
                ),

            "tmp_name" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php81FA.tmp",
                    "1" => "C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php820A.tmp"
                ),

            "error" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "0",
                    "1" => "0"
                ),

            "size" => Array
                (
                    "0" => "138108",
                    "1" => "142492"
                )

        )

);   


$counter = 0;

foreach ($_FILES AS $value) {

    $nbr = count($value['name']) - 1;

    for($x = 0; $x <= $nbr; $x++){
        foreach ($value AS $key => $elements) {           
            $newArray[$counter][$key]  = $elements[$x];  
        }         
        $counter++;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
?>
```

Comment: Oh, not like that. I am sorry for the misunderstanding. Please have a look to my update question.